# Symfony2 not rendering collection form data-prototype

Tags: symfony, twig

OK, this is rather awkward problem. I'm using `collection` form type in Symfony and after I configure it with

```
'prototype' => true,
'allow_add' => true
```

I would expect it to print prototype when I call either one of these in Twig template:

```
form_rest(form)
form_widget(form.subform.get('prototype'))
```

The problem is that Symfony prints that prototype **only** if collection contains at least one element.

Is this a bug I'm not aware of or I'm missing something?

Any idea would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated Symfony to it's latest stable and prototype is still acting strange:

- If no items exist it would render `<div data-prototype="...."></div>`
- Otherwise it would render prototype as pure HTML (not as `DIV`'s attribute above)

Since no out-of-box solution exists, I was forced to do `IF`-`ELSE` in my JS. That is, JS first checks for `data-prototype` element and falls back to other one if it does not exists.

As soon as I have some time to spare I will study this behavior and, if it's turn out to be undesired (as I suspect it is), will report it as a bug...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug, but I think there is no point in printing a form for the collection if it does not contain at least one element. If you're creating the collection, then you should create a dummy element and add it to your collection. This is not done automatically.

Comment: If I want to create an object from scratch I would like to be able to create all fields using jQuery. I could insert dummy object into collection but that seems to me a bit like quick 'n' dirty play...

Comment: Then maybe set a breakpoint in CollectionType.php line 27 and debug... I just had a look into it, and I don't understand why an element is necessary.

Comment: OK, it seems I was a little bit mistaken. In both cases prototype is being rendered, I just haven't been able to spot it right away but those 2 prototypes differ in many ways. I'll keep looking for a way to render single, more consistent, prototype which would allow me to use single JS code to add new items....

Comment: I have added an answer that concludes my findings. Maybe it will help someone with a similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

If the form data are empty, you can create a clone of the form and populate it with a dummy object. Use this clone for generating the prototype.